# Consider tossing a coin 2 times, there are 4 possible sequences of outcomes, what is the name of each sequence, in the context of stochastic process?

Tags: probability

In probability theory and related fields, a [stochastic process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_process) is a mathematical object usually defined as a family of random variables.

In probability and statistics, a [Bernoulli process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_process) (named after Jacob Bernoulli) is a finite or infinite sequence of binary random variables, so it is a discrete-time stochastic process that takes only two values, canonically 0 and 1.

Per this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_process)

It is reasonable to consider tossing a coin 2 times as a Bernoulli process.

The coin in this experiment is possibly unfair, but with consistent unfairness.

```
(0, 0) represents (tail, tail)
(0, 1) represents (tail, head)
(1, 0) represents (head, tail)
(1, 1) represents (head, head)
```

In the context of Bernoulli trial, each sequence is called A possible outcome. There are 4 possible outcomes in this case, all of which constitute the [sample space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_space) of this experiment.

So, what is the name of each sequence above, in the context of stochastic process or Bernoulli process?

Comment: Why do you need to call it a stochastic process? I think it makes more sense to call it a Bernoulli process [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_process).

Edit: realized bernoulii process was more accurate than bernoulli trial

Comment: @pedernv You are right, I've updated it. I'll be learning the link you gave.

Comment: the process you are describing is a bernoulli process. You do have a sequence of random variables (the two coins) each with two outcomes, and assuming fair coins the probability is the same for each

Comment: What do you wish to name? The 'events'?

Comment: @MartijnWeterings The possible sequence of the process (events)

Comment: Like "heads heads", "head tails" and so on?

Comment: @MartijnWeterings Exactly!

Comment: They can be called "tail, tail" "tail, head" "head, tail" and "head, head". Or replace the labels 'head and tail' with whatever you like, for instance '0 and 1' or 'success and failure'.

Comment: "Sample path" is a common term.